# How to add 'Pull to refresh'/ 'Load more' in UICollectionView using swift? (for both vertical and horizontal)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

How to add 'Pull to refresh'/ 'Load more' functionality in `UICollectionView` using swift? (for both vertical and horizontal)

Any library is available for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi can't find any library available for UICollectionView load more for both vertical and horizontal. So I have created a sample code for it. Check the code here.
https://github.com/arunpkumar92/InfiniteUICollectionView

[image]